# Сколько раз(2 или 3) в этом коде вызывается деструктор? Опишите , пожалуйста, поэтапно

Tags: c++, классы, деструктор

Компилятор говорит, что 2, но по идее мы трижды обращаемся к одной области памяти

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class sample {
    char *s;
public:
    sample() {
        s = 0;
    }
    ~sample() {
        if(s) delete [] s;
        cout << "Освобождение s-памяти.\n";
    }
    void show() {
        cout << s << "\n";
    }
    void set(char *str);
};
// Загрузка строки.
void sample::set(char *str)
{
    s = new char[strlen(str)+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}
//Эта функция возвращает объект типа sample.
sample input()
{
    char instr[80];
    sample str;
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    cin >> instr;
    str.set(instr);
    return str;
}
int main()
{
    sample ob;
    // Присваиваем объект, возвращаемый
    // функцией input(), объекту ob.
    ob = input(); // Эта инструкция генерирует ошибку(или вывод мусор)
    ob.show(); // Отображение "мусора".
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Начнем с того, что ваша программа будет дважды освобождать одну и ту же память - так что UB...

Comment: @Harry я знаю, я рассматриваю потенциальные проблемы при возвращении объектов. Но вопрос тот же. Сколько раз вызывается деструктор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **main** создаётся пустой объект. В **input** конструируем класс, при возврате **return** делаем временную копию с стеке. В конце метода **input** вызывается деструктор локальной переменной **str**. Временная копия становится неликвидной из-за того , что строка **s** указывает на удалённый участок памяти. Далее в **main** вы копируете неликвидный временный объект. Этот временный объект удаляется. Деструктор временного объекта рушится из-за того, что строка уже удалена. А если-бы дошёл ход до **main** деструктор бы вызывался ещё раз (третий) в **main**. На всё ту-же удалённую строку была-бы проблема. По-поводу два или три раза деструктор вызывался может быть расплывчатая тема оптимизации компилятора. Из **input** вы передаёте локальную переменную. А компилятор может соптимизировать: не удалять два раза. Ответ : при оптимизации два деструктора, без оптимизации три.

Comment: Объяснили , как надо.  Отлично

Answer (score 3):

Два (объект `str` в `input()` и `ob` в `main()`).

Но учтите, что у вас копирование и присваивание - мелкие, так что у вас не программа, а сплошная проблема...

Comment: Так ,а при `sample() { s = 0; }`  деструктор сразу не вызывается? Немного плаваю в этой теме просто

Comment: Просто , вот что значит **копирование и присваивание - мелкие** ?

Comment: Помимо всего этого, если вызвать метод `set` более одного раза, будет утечка памяти.

Comment: 1. Нет, здесь нет никакого уничтожения объекта. 2. Мелкие - значит, что они копируют ваш указатель на выделенное место в памяти. И в деструкторе каждый объект старательно освобождает одну и ту же память - что паршиво. Вы должны выделять новую память и копировать туда содержимое (глубокое копирование-присваивание). Ну, и не забывать удалять старую память - иначе как справедливо указали, в `set` будет утечка памяти.

Comment: @MickeyU По поводу копирования и присваивания: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three